# Opel corsa's horn alarms when car is locked

Tags: power-windows, alarm, opel, horn

My Opel Corsa's horn keeps honking when I lock the car the same way it is supposed to if a window were to be left open, but it does this even when no window is left open. The one thing that could cause this is that the right rear window does not work. Could this be the cause of the problem?

Comment: It may be the one window which is not working is not *completely* closed. Either that or whatever sensor which tells the body control module (BCM) the window is closed is malfunctioning. This may be at the "broken" window, but could be at any of them. And, you could be right, the fact that the window is not working could also have something to do with it. It could be the window shares the same sensor with the BCM which allows it to roll the window down. I would definitely start at the "broken" window for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

It is because of the broken electric window. Mine does the same, trying to find out if the opel garage can disable it as it's very annoying when it honks twice while locking it in a parking lot. I disconnected my hooter but that is causing more of a danger than solving the loud honking noise when locking the car...

Comment: Besides being unsafe, there's a good chance that driving with your horn disconnected is illegal.  It certainly is in my jurisdiction.